# The ssh agent cannot 'resolve hostname' when called from within a bash script

Tags: ssh, bash, remote-access, hostname, ssh-agent

I have a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r some_directory remote_host:~
```

which I made executable with `chmod u+x`. The remote_host has been defined in my .ssh/config as follows:

```
Host remote_host
HostName ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/path_to_pem_file/pem_file.pem
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

when I call `scp -r some_directory remote_host:~` or `ssh remote_host` it works without problems to access the remote machine via ssh. However inside the bash script it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mochacle: Name or service not known
lost connection
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mochacle: Name or service not known
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mochacle: Name or service not known
```

irrespective of whether I sudo the execution of the script or not.

Comment: Have you tried the FQDN?

Comment: When you run the script with `sudo`, it's running as root and hence will look in root's ~/.ssh/config file, not yours; if that doesn't have an entry for remote_host, you'll get this result. When you use the script without `sudo` and get this error, are you also running it as root (or some other user) via some other means?

Comment: @Zac67: What is FQDN?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson: I will try this tomorrow. I think this is the issue.

Comment: @Marlo FQDN = Fully Qualified Domain Name, i.e. ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com. That is, have you tried `sudo scp -r -i ~/path_to_pem_file/pem_file.pem some_directory -o IdentitiesOnly=yes ubuntu@ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~`